# Changing the timezone strings of date_lang.php

Tags: codeigniter, date, timezone

CodeIgniter stores timezones for its date class in

`system/language/english/date_lang.php`

I would like to change the strings in this file so that

```
$lang['UM12']   = '(UTC -12:00) Baker/Howland Island';
$lang['UM11']   = '(UTC -11:00) Samoa Time Zone, Niue';
```

would instead be

```
$lang['-12:00'] = '(UTC -12:00) Baker/Howland Island';
$lang['-11:00'] = '(UTC -11:00) Samoa Time Zone, Niue';
```

Is this possible at all?

Any change I make to the `UM__` portion of one line makes it show as a blank on the dropdown. The remaining (unchanged) lines appear OK.

I have also tried to clone this file to `application/language/english/` with similar bad results.

Any insights on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this would require hacks to the `date_helper.php` file which I am not willing to do.

Instead, the date class in CI has the `timezones()` function which allows you to convert from, for example, `UM5` to `-5`. In that case one can wrap this function around the `U__` value coming from the view/dropdown -- and then save it to DB as `-5` or some other `INT`.

Since I want to show the user their selected timezone on that same dropdown, I am forced to have DB fields for the `U__` **and** `INT` timezone formats. As far as I know, there is no CI function to convert from `-5` to `UM5`.

So, for the user, I pull the `U__` format into the view to autopopulate the dropdown.

For timezone conversions and such, I use the `INT` format.